# NullPointerException when creating a BoundStatement using datastax driver

Tags: cassandra, nullpointerexception, datastax

I am seeing the following error occasionally when creating a BoundBtatement using datastax driver

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.datastax.driver.core.BoundStatement.<init>(BoundStatement.java:79)
```

I create a PreparedStatement once during initialization and use it when creating the BoundStatement

```
PreparedStatement preparedStatement;
public void init() {
    RegularStatement temp;
    temp = insertInto(KEYSPACE, TABLE)
        .value(field_id, bindMarker(field_id))
    preparedStatement = session.prepare(temp);
}

public void doWork() {
    new BoundStatement(preparedStatement)
        .setString(field_id, "field_id")
}
```

So it occasionally throws NullPointerException during the BoundStatement initialization. I have retries so it eventually succeeds. But I wanted to know the reason behind this occasional NullPointerException.

I used to see that error if the cassandra table was not created and the session was not valid. But now even though the tables are there and things work ~100% of the time, I am still seeing these occasional error logs.

Comment: What version of the driver?

Comment: Did you ever solve it? Have the same issue...